# Why does this SQL query that works in MS Access not work in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following query works in MS Access, but it does not work in MS SQL Server:

```
SELECT
  tblSession.PatientID as PID,
  max(tblSession.SessionAttend) - 
    min(tblSession.SessionAttend) + 1 as NumSA,
  max(tblSession.SessionSched) - 
    min(tblSession.SessionSched) + 1 as NumSS FROM
  (
    SELECT top 100 percent
      tblSession.PatientID,
      tblSession.SessionNumber,
      tblSession.SessionDate,
      tblSession.SessionAttend,
      tblSession.SessionSched FROM
      tblPatient INNER JOIN tblSession ON
        tblPatient.PatientID = tblSession.PatientID) WHERE
        (tblSession.SessionDate >= '12/8/2010') AND
        (tblSession.SessionDate <= '5/18/2011') AND
        (tblSession.Status = '2') ORDER BY 
          tblSession.PatientID, tblSession.SessionNumber
  ) GROUP BY tblSession.PatientID
```

In SQL Server, it gives the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'."  When I hover over the GROUP keyword, the tooltip displays "Incorrect syntax near 'GROUP'.  Expecting AS, ID, or QUOTED_ID."  I don't understand.  Can anyone tell me how to make this query work?

Comment: you need an alias for the subquery `from (...) t group by t.PatientId`

Comment: I believe you nested SELECT needs an alias. So the last line ") GROUP BY tblSession.PatientID" needs to have something like ") AS tbl GROUP BY tblSession.PatientID". I could be wrong...

Comment: Irreleveant question but why do you have that `TOP 100 percent`?

Comment: @ypercube I've seen `top 100 percent` used to allow adding an order by to a view. Seems unnecessary here...

Comment: @dotjoe Also seems unnecessary in a view, since SQL Server is not bound to honor the `ORDER BY` - the `ORDER BY` is only allowed combined with `TOP`, and indicates which rows to include, not what order to present them. It's an old trick that worked in 2000 but not in today's optimizer (at least not by default) - today's optimizer actually just throws away both the `TOP` and the `ORDER BY` in this case. The only way to guarantee `ORDER BY` against that view is to apply `ORDER BY` on the outer query.

Comment: @ypercube: You're right, that first `TOP 100 PERCENT` was not necessary.  I removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derived table in `()` needs an alias, and its column references in the `SELECT` list updated accordingly:

```
SELECT top 100 percent
  ALIASNAME.PatientID as PID,
  max(ALIASNAME.SessionAttend) - 
    min(ALIASNAME.SessionAttend) + 1 as NumSA,
  max(ALIASNAME.SessionSched) - 
    min(ALIASNAME.SessionSched) + 1 as NumSS FROM
  (
    SELECT top 100 percent
      tblSession.PatientID,
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
          tblSession.PatientID, tblSession.SessionNumber
  -- This derived table needs an alias
  ) ALIASNAME 
  GROUP BY ALIASNAME.PatientID
```

Comment: He will also need to update his field aliases since I'm guessing `tblsession` won't resolve.